# Problem com array_merge e WHILE - PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, json, array, codeigniter

Bom dia!

Eu tenho um while que lê todas as linhas de um arquivo especifico, dentro desse while ele chamada um método que retorna um valor. Esse valor é um array, e estou dando um array_merge pra cada array mas quando eu dou o return fora do while , ele me retorna apenas 1 resultado ;/

Segue código:

```
        if (!$lendo){
            echo "Erro ao abrir a URL.";
            exit;
        }

        $i = 1;
        $x = 1;
        $cod_motivo = "  ";
        $b = 4;
        $aa = "";
        $arrayRetorno = array();
        $arrayfinal = array();
        $resultado = "";
        while (!feof($lendo)) {

            $linha = fgets($lendo,401);

            $rr = "<pre>".$linha."</pre>";

            $xtamanho_linha = strlen($linha);
                    $dados = array(
                        'b' => $b,
                        'rr' => $rr,
                        'xx' => $x,
                        'i' => $i
                    );

                    //Chamada do metodo no mesmo arquivo que dá um return em um valor.

                    $teste = $this->segmento($dados,$total_itens_processados,$total_valor_nominal);

                    //teria que juntar um array vazio com o array retornando no teste;
                    $arrayfinal = array_merge($arrayRetorno,$teste);
                $i++;
        }

        //Me retorna apenas 1 valor;
        var_dump($teste);
```

Answer (score 0):

O array_merge precisa de um atributo inicial que vai ser a array na qual vai fundir os elementos. Você não precisa declarar a uma variável, eu acho. Apenas execute a função

[Documentação do array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php)

`$arrayFinal = array_merge($arrayFinal, [$arrayRetorno, $teste])`

Comment: Edição...Antes dava erro

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o problema é que você está fazendo o merge entre `$arrayRetorno` e `$teste`, mas o resultado está sendo no `$arrayFinal`, dessa forma o `$arrayFinal` será só o `$teste`.

Acho que isso resolveria o problema:

```
$arrayfinal = array_merge($arrayfinal,$teste);
```

*Dessa forma, o `$arrayfinal` será combinado com o `$teste`, a cada execução do loop.*